# How to execute SqlQuery with Entity Framework Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework 6, I can execute a raw SQL query on the database using the following command:

```
IEnumerable<string> Contact.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT a.title FROM a JOIN b ON b.Id = a.aId WHERE b.Status = 10");
```

On a new project, I am trying to use Entity Framework Core 2.1. I have a need to execute raw SQL query. While googling, I can see that the extension `SqlQuery` was changed to `FromSql`. However, `FromSql` only exists on the `DbSet<>` not on the `DbContext.Database`.

How can I run `FromSql` outside the `DbSet<>`? The method `FromSql` does not exists on the database object `DbContext.Database.FromSql<>`.

Comment: I updated my answer. With EF Core 2.1 RC 1, Microsoft introduced a new feature DbQuery<T> and you can call FromSql on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 34):

**Updates**

This is wokring for EF Core 2.1 but if you're using EF Core 3.0 or higher versions please refer to this [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core/50452479#50452479).

---

> I can see that the extension SqlQuery was changed to FromSql

But the new `FromSql` method is more restrcitive than `SqlQuery`. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) of that method explains that it exists some limitations like:

> SQL queries can only be used to return ***entity types that are part of
> your model***. There is an enhancement on our backlog to [enable returning ad-hoc types from raw SQL queries](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1862).
> The SQL query must return data for ***all properties of the entity or query type***.
>
> [...]
> Update: more recent GitHub dotnet/efcore discussion [Support raw SQL queries without defining an entity type for the result #10753](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10753)

So in your case the SQL query you're using is the following:

```
SELECT a.title FROM a JOIN b ON b.Id = a.aId WHERE b.Status = 10
```

As the documentation said you can only use `FromSql` with **entity or query type**. Your SQL query doesn't return all data of your entity defined in your model but it only returns one column of your entity. By the way a new feature is introduced in EF Core 2.1 which is in Release Candidate since 7 may 2018. Microsoft says:

> EF Core 2.1 RC1 is a “go live” release, which means once you test that
> your application works correctly with RC1, you can use it in
> production and obtain support from Microsoft, but you should still
> update to the final stable release once it’s available.

##Using FromSql on query type##

What is a [query type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types):

> An EF Core model can now include query types. Unlike
> entity types, query types do not have keys defined on them and cannot
> be inserted, deleted or updated (i.e. they are read-only), but they
> can be returned directly by queries. Some of the usage scenarios for
> query types are: mapping to views without primary keys, mapping to tables without primary keys, mapping to queries defined in the model, serving as the return type for FromSql() queries

If you want to use query type feature with your SQL text you first define a  class, let's name it `MySuperClass`:

```
public class MySuperClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `DbContext` class defined a property of type `DbQuery<MySuperClass>` like below:

```
public DbQuery<MySuperClass> MySuperQuery { get; set; }
```

Finally you can use `FromSql` on it like below:

```
var result = context.MySuperQuery.FromSql("SELECT a.title FROM a JOIN b ON b.Id = a.aId WHERE b.Status = 10").ToList().First();
var title = result.Title;
```

##Don't want to use `DbQuery<T>`##
If you don't want to use `DbQuery<T>` and don't want to define a class that contains only one property then you can use `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` like @**vivek nuna** did in his answer(his answer is partially correct). But you must know that returned value by that method is the number of rows affected by your query. Also you must put your title as an output parameter so make your query a stored procedure. Use `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` or `ExecuteSqlCommand` and after that read the output parameter you passed when calling the method.

A simpler way without creating a stored procedure therefore not using `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` or `ExecuteSqlCommand` is to the following code:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    const string query = "SELECT a.title FROM a JOIN b ON b.Id = a.aId WHERE b.Status = 10";
    command.CommandText = query;
    var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        var title = reader.GetString(0);
        // Do whatever you want with title 
    }
}
```

You can make this logic a helper method that will recevie your SQL Query and returns the desired data. But I recommend you use [Dapper.Net](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) whcih contains a lot of helpers methods that will help to deal easily with RAW SQL like we do above and also sharing the smae connection with `DbContext`.

Comment: Where are you setting the value of the property `public DbQuery<MySuperClass> MySuperQuery { get; set; }`?  I'm trying to figure out where to get an instance of `DbQuery` because the class is abstract.  Do I have to make a custom one?  There's nothing to override in it, so I don't get it.

Comment: You need a class that EF can instantiate when doing materialization. So abstract class will not work. You need a custom one @rory.ap

Comment: how to pass parameters?

Comment: Note that `DbQuery` has been replaced with keyless entity types using `DbSet` in EF Core 3.

Comment: Why add this answer instead of just marking the question as a duplicate of [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452479)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` method which is defined in `RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions` class of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly by the following way.

```
_databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(<Your parameters>)
```

Comment: This only executes the SQL, it does not return a result set