# LINQ with group_concat - get linked tabe results in one field

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Good morning,

I have following SQLite query which I need to transfer to LINQ:

```
"SELECT hostname, macaddress, uuid, group_concat(collection.collection_name) AS collection, daterequested, daterealized, requester, action_name AS action, done_name as done, comment FROM computerimport 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN action ON action.action_id = computerimport.action_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN done ON done.done_id = computerimport.done_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN computercollection ON computerimport.computer_id = computercollection.computer_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN collection ON computercollection.collection_id = collection.collection_id
                    GROUP BY computerimport.computer_id
                    ORDER BY daterequested;"
```

As you can see I have some LEFT OUTER JOINs and also using a group_concat to put everything from one table in just one field so that when a device exists in the computercollection twice I only get one record.
My LINQ query looks like this;

```
await (from ci in _context.ComputerImports
                      join re in _context.Results on ci.result_id equals re.result_id
                      join ac in _context.Actions on ci.action_id equals ac.action_id
                      join cc in _context.ComputerCollections on ci.computer_id equals cc.computer_id into gjcc
                         from subcc in gjcc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join co in _context.Collections on subcc.collection_id equals co.collection_id into gjco
                         from subco in gjco.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new OverviewViewModel
                                {
                                    computer_id = ci.computer_id,
                                    hostname = ci.hostname, 
                                    uuid = ci.uuid,
                                    collection_id = subcc.collection_id,
                                    collection_name = subco.collection_displayname,
                                    daterequested = ci.daterequested,
                                    daterealized = ci.daterealized,
                                    action_id = ci.action_id,
                                    action_name = ac.action_name,
                                    result_id = ci.result_id, 
                                    result_name = re.result_name,
                                    comment = ci.comment
                                }).OrderByDescending(e => e.daterequested).ToListAsync();
```

But I also tried a group by with a String join:

```
await (from t in (from ci in _context.ComputerImports
                      join re in _context.Results on ci.result_id equals re.result_id
                      join ac in _context.Actions on ci.action_id equals ac.action_id
                      join cc in _context.ComputerCollections on ci.computer_id equals cc.computer_id into gjcc
                         from subcc in gjcc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join co in _context.Collections on subcc.collection_id equals co.collection_id into gjco
                         from subco in gjco.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new {ci.computer_id, ci.hostname, ci.uuid, subcc.collection_id, subco.collection_displayname, ci.daterequested, ci.daterealized, ci.action_id, ac.action_name, ci.result_id, re.result_name, ci.comment})
                    group t by new { t.computer_id, t.hostname, t.uuid, t.daterequested, t.daterealized, t.action_id, t.action_name, t.result_id, t.result_name, t.comment } into dg
                         select new OverviewViewModel
                                {
                                    computer_id = dg.Key.computer_id,
                                    hostname = dg.Key.hostname, 
                                    uuid = dg.Key.uuid,
                                    collection_id = dg.Key.result_id,
                                    collection_name = String.Join(",", dg.Select(d => d.collection_displayname).Distinct()),
                                    daterequested = dg.Key.daterequested,
                                    daterealized = dg.Key.daterealized,
                                    action_id = dg.Key.action_id,
                                    action_name = dg.Key.action_name,
                                    result_id = dg.Key.result_id, 
                                    result_name = dg.Key.result_name,
                                    comment = dg.Key.comment
                                }).OrderByDescending(e => e.daterequested).ToListAsync();
```

So far no luck. Is there a way to make this query easier? Right now, compared to the SQL language it does not feel very easy and readable.

---

Update:
In Powershell with MSSQL it seems also quite easy:

```
$query = "SELECT hostname, uuid, STRING_AGG (TRIM(collection.collection_displayname), ' - ') as collection, daterequested, daterealized, requester, action_name AS action, result_name as result, comment 
                    FROM computerimport 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN action ON action.action_id = computerimport.action_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN result ON result.result_id = computerimport.result_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN computercollection ON computerimport.computer_id = computercollection.computer_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN collection ON computercollection.collection_id = collection.collection_id
                    GROUP BY computerimport.computer_id, computerimport.hostname, computerimport.uuid, computerimport.daterequested, computerimport.requester, computerimport.daterealized, action_name, result_name, computerimport.comment
                    ORDER BY daterequested"
```

---

Update:

I took my working query and tried to create a new one out of it:

```
var result = ovm.GroupBy(cc => new {cc.computer_id, cc.hostname, cc.uuid, cc.daterequested, cc.daterealized, cc.action_id, cc.action_name, cc.result_id, cc.result_name, cc.comment})
                            .Select(dd => new { omputer_id = dd.Key.computer_id,
                                    hostname = dd.Key.hostname, 
                                    uuid = dd.Key.uuid,
                                    collection_name = String.Join(" - ", dd.Select(d => d.collection_name).Distinct()),
                                    daterequested = dd.Key.daterequested,
                                    daterealized = dd.Key.daterealized,
                                    action_id = dd.Key.action_id,
                                    action_name = dd.Key.action_name,
                                    result_id = dd.Key.result_id, 
                                    result_name = dd.Key.result_name,
                                    comment = dd.Key.comment});
```

Unfortunately result saying:
 Select(d => d.collection_name)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

---

Update:
As recommended I am trying to use a SQL statement like suggested here: [How to execute SqlQuery with Entity Framework Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402015/how-to-execute-sqlquery-with-entity-framework-core-2-1/50409786#50409786)

So I created a new class with the field I need, added it to the model builder:

```
public DbSet<OverviewQuery> OverviewQueries { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<OverviewQuery>().ToView(nameof(OverviewQueries)).HasNoKey();
```

But always when I try to run a joined table I get the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The underlying reader doesn't have as many fields as expected.
```

When I run it directly I have no issues:

```
           string sqlquery = @"SELECT computerimport.action_id FROM computerimport LEFT OUTER JOIN action ON action.action_id = computerimport.action_id" ; 
_context.OverviewQueries.FromSqlRaw(sqlquery).ToList();
```

---

Update:

Ok, the model has to have exact the same values which you want to pass, it can not have more:

```
string sqlquery = "SELECT computerimport.*, action.action_name, STRING_AGG(TRIM(collection.collection_name), ' - ') AS collection_name, STRING_AGG(TRIM(collection.collection_displayname), ' - ') AS collection_displayname, result.result_name " +
                            "FROM computerimport " + 
                            "LEFT OUTER JOIN action ON action.action_id = computerimport.action_id " +
                            "LEFT OUTER JOIN result ON result.result_id = computerimport.result_id " +
                            "LEFT OUTER JOIN computercollection ON computerimport.computer_id = computercollection.computer_id " +
                            "LEFT OUTER JOIN collection ON computercollection.collection_id = collection.collection_id " +
                            "GROUP BY computerimport.computer_id, computerimport.hostname, computerimport.uuid, computerimport.daterequested, computerimport.requester, computerimport.daterealized, computerimport.action_id, action_name, computerimport.result_id, result_name, computerimport.comment";


            var ovmraw = await _context.OverviewQueries.FromSqlRaw(sqlquery).ToListAsync();
```

OverviewQueries

public int computer_id { get; set;}

```
public string hostname {get; set;}
public string uuid {get; set;}
public Nullable<DateTime> daterequested {get; set;}  
public Nullable<DateTime> daterealized {get; set;}
public string requester {get; set;}
public int action_id {get; set;}
public int result_id {get; set;}
public string comment {get; set;}

// Values from other models
public string action_name {get; set;}
//public int? collection_id { get; set; }
public string collection_name {get; set;
public string collection_displayname {get; set;}
public string result_name {get; set;}
```

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement For SQL. Don't use it like this. It's a language used on top of an  ORM. It's the ORM's job to create joins from relations, not LINQs. And since LINQ isn't SQL, it doesn't have vendor-specific SQL extensions like MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT or SQL Server's STRING_AGG

Comment: What you wrote for Powershell isn't Powershell, it's just a SQL query. But LINQ isn't SQL. ORMs in general are *not* meant for reporting queries like the one you posted. Aggregate LINQ functions like `Min`, `Max` etc can only get you so far. It's better and usually faster to create a view and map your entity to that view.

Comment: I understand. What do you mean with create a View? Each table has a model and I have a View where I want to show combined information from this models, which is also working except the issue with the concatenation. I tried now FromSqlRaw but this only allows me to touch one table.

Answer (score 0):

As Panagiotis Kanavos said, I had to/ I switched to SQL and I got the query working. Also you have to be careful that the model you use. It has to have the exact attributes like your query does. Otherwise it will fail with the error message:

```
InvalidOperationException: The underlying reader doesn't have as many fields as expected.
```