# LINQ for many-to-many in EF Core 2

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, many-to-many

I have searched on google and stackoverflow for a while and yes I have found many articles on the subject but I still can't seem to know what I am doing wrong.

Problem: I do have a "link" table (many-to-many) between three tables:
- check
- car
- gate

My 'link' class looks like follows:

```
public class CheckCarGate
{
    public int CheckId { get; set; }
    public Check Check{ get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car{ get; set; }

    public int GateId { get; set; } 
    public Gate Gate { get; set; } 
}
```

DbContext:

```
public virtual DbSet<Car> Cars{ get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Gate> Gates { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Check> Checks{ get; set; }
```

// The key:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<CheckCarGate>().HasKey(p => new { p.CheckId, p.CarId, p.GateId });
    }
```

I did follow this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many when creating models. CheckCarGate is a navigation property in the entity models. E.g.

```
public class Gate
{
    public int GateId { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CheckCarGate> CheckCarGates { get; set; }
}
```

Code first created this table in the database. Now I'm trying to select all Checks with all Gates for one particular CarId.

I tried something like this:

```
var masterlist = _context.Checks.Where(p => p.CheckCarGate.Any(x => x.CarId == 12));
```

or:

```
var masterlist = _context.Checks
                .Include(p => p.CheckCarGate)
                .ThenInclude(p=>p.Gate)
                .Include(p=>p.CheckCarGate)
                .ThenInclude(p=>p.Car);
```

//Edit: I'm sorry for not giving enough information! Bear with me...

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

N.

Comment: Can you include your mappings? (EntityTypeConfiguration or modelBuilder configuration on the DbContext)  Also what issue are you seeing? Error, or empty values?

Comment: `_context.CheckCarGates.Include(x => x.Check).Include(x => x.Gate).Where(x => x.CarId == 12)).Select(x => new { x.Gate, x.Check });`

Comment: I'm not sure gate should have a CheckCarGate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is enough information here to answer your question; it appears like each check has its own checkcargate, which doesn't really make sense.

Assuming you had a table of checks and CheckCarGate table seperatatly, you can use where and select to make this query.

```
var out = CheckCarGateTable.Where(t => t.CarID == targetCarID)
          .Select(c => checks.getbyid(c.CheckID))
```

or, based on your class definition

```
var out = CheckCarGateTable.Where(t => t.CarID == targetCarID)
          .Select(c => c.Check))
```

First we get all CheckCarGates that refer to our target car, then we transform these into checks using the select call; out should be of type IEnumerable< Check >

and process the list like:

```
foreach (Check c in out)
{
     proc(c);
}
```

This is the best I can do with the information given.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for not providing enough information. As the CheckCarGate table is a 'link' table, I cannot use it with _context.xxxxx. It is a navigation property

Comment: @Nearshore That's your misconception. There's nothing that keeps you from including a property `DbSet<CheckCarGate>` in the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your OnModelCreating(...) should have more in it defining the relationship

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<CheckCarGate>().HasKey(p => new { p.CheckId, p.CarId, p.GateId });

        builder.Entity<CheckCarGate>().HasOne(c => c.car)
                                      .WithMany(c => c.check)
                                      .HasForeignKey(k => k.carId)

        ...
    }
```

I'm not sure how you change your query after that, the documentation link you provided didn't have example usage.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up looking for a LINQ solution. (2 days wasted).

Instead I decided to use raw sql and store the data in a new object.

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/355714/pius and his solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013305/848642