# Entity Framework Core manual sql query within an existing transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, entity-framework-core

Similar to the question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42932812/1321510 we need to execute a raw sql query.  For the query we don't have any db context model (so any `.FromSql` answers won't work for us). However we need to execute it within an existing transaction (created with `context.Database.BeginTransaction()`). All solutions found on SO do not work with existing transactions.

Example:

```
var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.Transaction = context.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction();

        var executeReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        var values = new object[executeReader.FieldCount];

        if (!executeReader.Read())
        {
            return values;
        }
        executeReader.GetValues(values);

        return values;
    }
}
```

Commiting the transaction then throws `System.InvalidOperationException: 'This MySqlConnection is already in use. See https://fl.vu/mysql-conn-reuse'`.
The provided link in the exception doesn't seem helpful at all, since we're neither using async nor using the connection whilst reading from it.

We're using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` as the database connector.

Comment: DId you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @Benni I sadly did not. I ended up rewriting the raw SQL Statements into LINQ (that was possible only because the requirements changed).