# How to return data from different tables using Sql Query in EF Core without using table valued functions/Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

How can i select data from two tables using SQL query using ef core.
Below are two tables

```
 public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // Don't want to return this.
        public string Name { get; set; } // Only want to return this.
    }

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

I want to execute `Select P.Name , C.Name from tblCategory C JOIN tblProduct P ON C.Id = P.CategoryId`
in entity framework core.

One option is to use table valued functions but i dont want to consider it?
I dont want to use linq because the sql generated is not efficient. 
Above is just an example not a real scenario.

Comment: Yes,i do have linq option but the sql is not efficient. I want to execute sql query

Comment: Dapper and an sql query

Comment: Linq would generate just the query you want, you can enable logging to verify it. What are your findings that linq is not efficient?

Comment: @MichaelRandall You can also recommend  pure ADO.NET  :) Yes dapper is an option. but my entire repository is implemented in entity framework core

Comment: @tiger yeah but dapper is awesome ;)

Comment: @MichaelRandall. totally Agreed but still not fast than ado.net reader. Anyways...I asked because i want to know that is it possible in efcore ? or there is a limitation.?

Comment: you can use .FromSqlRaw(Select P.Name , C.Name from tblCategory C JOIN tblProduct P ON C.Id = P.CategoryId) in Entity Framework Core. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: also check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this using EF Core instead of ADO.NET or Dapper, you can use raw Sql Queries as below:

EF Core 2.1 example:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```

In EF Core 3.1, `FromSql` is Obsolete, Hence use `FromSqlRaw`

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs")
    .ToList();
```

Similarly, your query can be executed as

```
var results = context.ProductCategories.FromSqlRaw(Select P.Name as ProductName, C.Name as CategoryName from tblCategory C JOIN tblProduct P ON C.Id = P.CategoryId)
```

Note: Also, you need to define ProductCategories in context class.

```
public DbQuery<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
```

---

ProductCategory.cs

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Here, ProductCategory is known as query type in EF Core 2.1. 
In EF Core 3.0 the concept was renamed to keyless entity types. It serves as return type for raw Sql Queries.

You can refer [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for more details

Comment: Will i t create a new table in database by the name of ProductCateories?

Comment: Not required.. I have updated the answer to use DbQuery instead of DbSet

Comment: It means if i want to return a different type it has be declared in Context??

Comment: ya.. you need to define a class and then declare it in Context..

Comment: Won't the change in the dbcontext class be overwritten by scaffold commands that regenerate the dbcontext?

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute an SQL statement with the query that you want:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    {
       string query = @"select P.Name, C.Name from tblCategory C JOIN P ON C.Id=P.CategoryId";
       result = (await connection.QueryAsync<MyDto>(query)).ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: My Question is specific to EF Core. You answered would have been appropriate if i asked how to do with dapper?

Answer (score 0):

In EF you would normally not use a raw SQL query for something so simple.

Instead, add a [Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) to from Product to Category:

```
public class Category
{
     public int Id { get; set; } // Don't want to return this.
     public string Name { get; set; } // Only want to return this.
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category {get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can write a LINQ query like

```
from p in db.Product
   select new {ProductName = p.Name, CategoryName = p.Category.Name };
```

In Code-First, this will also ensure that you can't have a Product whose CategoryId is not the Id of some Category by creating a Foreign Key in the database, and (at least for SQL Server) create a non-clustered index on Product.CategoryId for improved performance.