# How to execute a sql procedure as a raw query in entity framewrok core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

What is the Alternate for SqlQuery in EF Core2.0 I dont want to create a model for executing the procedure

```
     var result =  _context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("TWS_config_MidOfficeSystems_Validate @mo,@ga,@pcc,@xmo",
                                   parameters: new SqlParameter[]
                                   {   new SqlParameter("@mo",lineData),
                                    new SqlParameter("@ga", gdsAccessId),
                                    new SqlParameter("@pcc", crsPCC),
                                    new SqlParameter("@xmo", bkMidOfficeCode),
                                   }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 0):

As EF Core tightly coupled, You have to create `class` with properties coming from stored procedure.

```
 public class ExampleClass
 {            
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }            
 }
```

In `ApplicationDbContext.cs` add that class as `DbQuery`

```
 public DbQuery<ExampleClass> ExampleClassDbQuery { get; set; }
```

Implement `Dependency Injection` into your `controller` or `services`

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;


    public ExampleService(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        _db = applicationDbContext;  
    }
```

Then call stored procedure like this:

```
_db.ExampleClassDbQuery.FromSql("storedProcedureName", []parameters);
```

For more to know about running raw queries using `FromSql` please follow this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)