# How do you write a join statement when using FromSqlRaw in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am converting an existing application and I am using the existing database structure.

This is the model of the data I am querying:

```
public partial class StaffNotes
{
        public int RecordNumber { get; set; }
        public double? ContactNumber { get; set; }
        public double? WriteNumber { get; set; }
        public double? ToStaff { get; set; }
        public double? FromStaff { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CriticalDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? NoteDate { get; set; }
        public int? TicketNumber { get; set; }
        public bool Imp { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of displaying the number of the ToStaff, I would like to display the appropriate name.

I have written the following query:

```
var staffNotes = _context.StaffNotes.FromSql("Select s.record_number, s.contact_number, s.To_Staff, s.From_Staff, s.Note_Date, s.Ticket_Number, s.Imp, s.Critical_Date, S.Note, s.write_number, c.first_name, c.last_name from staffnotes s, contacts c where s.contact_number = c.contact_number and s.Contact_Number = " + id).ToList();
```

My code runs and I'm not getting any errors. The only issue is the `first_name` and `last_name` do not appear in the data.

Is this because it is not part of the model? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Comment: I added those properties and it is working.  I'm just wondering is there away around doing that in case I needed to do more/advanced join statements?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also - if you're using EF Core - why on earth are you using such an awful, clunky, messy SQL - can't you just load the entity you're interested in from your EF Core `DbContext` and be done with it??

Comment: I’m still a student of the entity framework.  How can you write the equivalent of a join statement in ET?

Answer (score 0):

I added the missing properties and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

you must use FromSqlRaw  with using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; instead of FromSql

var staffNotes = _context.StaffNotes.FromSql**Raw**("Select s.record_number, s.contact_number, s.To_Staff, s.From_Staff, s.Note_Date, s.Ticket_Number, s.Imp, s.Critical_Date, S.Note, s.write_number, c.first_name, c.last_name from staffnotes s, contacts c where s.contact_number = c.contact_number and s.Contact_Number = " + id).ToList();