# C# Entity Framework Core write raw SQL without model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

First of all, I have seen this post: [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core) but I feel like it does not answer my question.

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project with Entity Framework Core (newest at this date).

What I need to do is:

```
public IActionResult MyView(string NameOfTable)
{
    // send model that is same as NameOfTable 
    // or
    // send something like List<string> that has properties and names of columns  
    return View();
}
```

What I want to do is call a function and send the name of a table in database. It will find the table in the database and return the properties of table (column names, types of columns[int/ varchar..]).

What I think will work: either write raw SQL to database.

What I think is good answer: some snippet of how to write raw SQL to query the database without knowing a model. Or some way of overcoming this problem.

Thanks for everything. Sorry if this is dumb question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I am very sleepy as its 2 in morning at my timezone and was really annoyed by this coplication in my code. I am posting solution.

Comment: I am confused why you are using entity framework, but not actually using it really. Seems kinda weird, but I am sure its for a reason. Why not just use DbSet, create migration, apply it, and then use them in a context like EF wants you too?

Comment: I am using it properly in my whole solution so I want it to be something like project wide and I dont want to download more libraries for one controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you all. I have found solution. Here it is:

```
public class AA
{
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

private async Task pokus()
{
    List<AA> groups = new List<AA>();
    var conn = _db.Database.GetDbConnection();
    try
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
            command.CommandText = query;
            DbDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var row = new AA { One = reader.GetString(1), Two = reader.GetString(2) };
                        groups.Add(row);
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dont have rows");
            }
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    foreach(AA s in groups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s.One);
        Console.WriteLine(s.Two);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help somebody.