# How to return a list of int in Entity Framework Core using FromSqlRaw?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have this sql query which uses raw sql in Entity Framework 6 and return a list of integer.

```
var sqlString = "SELECT DISTINCT A.ListId FROM ABC A INNER JOIN ABCLists B ON B.Id = A.ListId"

var recordIds = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sqlString).ToList();
```

How to convert this above into Entity Framework Core 3?

I tried with EF Core, but not sure where to define it to return as list int type. Below is what I have.

```
var recordIds = _djContext.ABC.FromSqlRaw(sqlString).ToList();
```

Notes: I don't need LINQ version but only raw SQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF 3.0 you  need to declare a dedicated type which is known as [Keyless entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations)

```
[Keyless]
public class SomeType
{
    public int Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Then you define a DbSet for it as usual

```
public DbSet<SomeType> SomeTypes { get; set; }
```

> **Note:**  [Keyless] attribute became available in EFCore 5.0. For EF 3.0 You can use fluent  configuration calling .HasNoKey() method on it:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeType>().HasNoKey();
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
var result = context.SomeTypes.FromSqlRaw(sqlString).ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

In fact you just have to "project" the query result with `Select`:

```cs
string sqlString = "SELECT A.Id FROM ABC A INNER JOIN ABCLists B ON B.Id = A.Id";
List<int> recordIds = _djContext.ABC.FromSqlRaw(sqlString).Select(abc => abc.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of: [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core) . Anyway, the answers there describe how to do that without creating useless "entities".