# How to implement Raw SQL without model in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core 5 MVC, I have:

```
dbContext = mfdDbContext

var myquery = select * from teachers order by id desc
```

The normal convention is this:

```
var results = mfdDbContext.SomeModel
                          .FromSqlRaw("select id, firstName, lastName from teachers order by id desc")
                          .ToList();
```

But I don't have a model class.

How do I implement the above raw query without a model? Then generate my own model.

Comment: Don't use Entity Framework for that query?

Comment: @gunr2171 - What do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with EF. You have to have model class anyway. That's why EF is so powerful.

Instead, you could use Dapper
https://dapper-tutorial.net/query

```
string sql = "select * from teachers order by id desc";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{    
    var data = connection.Query(sql).ToList();

    // use data
}
```

but anyway, you have manually to get the columns. I would recommend to have a DB Model registered with EF, it will make your life easier.

Comment: Is there a way to bring in the DbContext here  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))   instead of the Connection string? Since I have this inside DBContext      private readonly string Conn ="Server=myserver;Database=myDB;User Id=myuser;Password=mypw;";

Comment: @midowu i think you can try `_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString`

Comment: Do you mean I replace using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) with _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString

Comment: @midowu use this `using (var connection = new SqlConnection(mfdDbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString))`