# How to define and populate a data transfer object from sql in EF5 core?

Tags: c#, ef-core-5.0

I am used to DBSet mapping to a blog table in the database
But looking at the [.FromSqlRaw docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) it seems it need not.
For example

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogs")
    .ToList();
```

Suppose I don't actually want a blogs table in the database.
Do I still create a DbSet for one so that I can define my data transfer object?

I have been using an alternative method that makes use of DbDataReader with a mapping

```
Func<DbDataReader, T> map
```

But the catch is that I then need to refer to the ordinal of the properties
For example

```
var results = MyDataHelpers.RawSqlQuery( sql, x => new Dto
{
     Id = x.GetInt16(0),
     Name = x.GetString(1)
}  ).
```

I don't want to do this ( or use reflection or automapper as a work around) so this question is not a duplicate of [Raw Sql without DbSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

I don't mind DbSet per se but how do I do that when there is no table?

[Update]

I tried the following test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void T040_DbSetForDto()
    {
        var db = DataHelpers.MakeDbContext();
        var temps = db.DtoInts.FromSqlRaw("select top 1 Id from mytable").ToList();
        Assert.IsTrue(temps.Any());
    }
```

with the DBContext containing

```
 public DbSet<DtoTempInt> DtoTempInts { get; set; }
```

and

```
public class DtoTempInt
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and OnModelCreating containing

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DtoTempInt>().HasNoKey();
```

However the test fails with

```
 Message: 
Test method TestProject1.UnitTest1.T040_DbSetForDto threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

  Stack Trace: 
ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source)
ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitBlockExpressions(ExpressionVisitor visitor, BlockExpression block)
ExpressionVisitor.VisitBlock(BlockExpression node)
BlockExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
<8 more frames...>
Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
List`1.ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I am using net5.0 and

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.13" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="5.0.13" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.13" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @Progman thank you. I updated the question to show that I dont want to define the ordinal of the properties as I understand is needed using RawSqlQuery.  Maybe there is a way to mark the DBSet as not mapped?

Comment: Experimenting with marking all fields in the DbSet Dto as [NotMapped]

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
        [TestMethod]
        public void T040_DbSetForDto()
        {
            var db = DataHelpers.MakeDbContext();
            var temps = db.DtoInts.FromSqlRaw("select top 1 Id from mytable").ToList();
            
            Assert.IsTrue(temps.Any());
            var temp = temps.FirstOrDefault();
            Trace.WriteLine($"First id is {temp.Id}");
        }
}
```

My error message  may have been that I had put a [NotMapped] tag on the Id property.
It was also important to have

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DtoTempInt>().HasNoKey();
```

in OnModelCreating

I was also thinking that DbSet should only be used for actual data tables, but this is not true.