# Can I get return type from stored procedure without creating DbSet in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Supposedly, I have a simple `DbContext` with `Blog` and `Post` models:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have a stored procedure that returns some DTO:

```
[Keyless]
public class BlogPostDto
{
    public string PostTitle { get; init; }
    public string BlogName { get; init; }
}
```

Today I put the following into `DbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext {
    public virtual DbSet<BlogPostDto> NeverUseIt { get; set; }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPostDto>().ToView(null);
    }
}
```

And then I can get Stored Procedure results shaped in the way I want:

```
List<BlogPostDto> results = await db.Set<BlogPostDto>().FromSqlRaw($"EXEC MyProc").ToListAsync();
```

So, my question is, do I **have** to add my `BlogPostDto` into `DbContext`? I know that in EF Core 3 I did; but there were a large number of improvements since then. Creating a bogus DbSet and mapping it to non-existent view just feels counter-intuitive!

The closest I found in most current documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations). The very first example of context is *Serving as the return type for raw SQL queries.* - but the article assumes that I have a matching view already in the database.

**UPDATE**: It looks like `ToView(null)` is not necessary - just `DbSet<>`

Comment: The DbContext must know how to understand the data. You can immediately dispose it after the query, if you want to.

Comment: May be this is what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping?source=recommendations

Comment: @PoulBak - Indeed, I've been using Functions for years without the need to create an entry in DbContext. However, I need to be able to invoke stored procedure by name dynamically. so, this approach won't work. I guess, for now I'll continue to add return types in DbContext

Comment: You do not need a DbSet with this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.SqlQuery/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @PoulBak - the linked post says the same thing as my question: that in EF Core 3 you need to mark the class as `.HasNoKey()` (in EF Core 5 you can mark it with `KeyLess` attribute) **and** you need to add it to `DbSet`. My question is based on that post (among many others) - is it possible to *not* add it to `DbContext`. Apparently, the answer is still NO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed in that regard so far from what you see in the EF Core 6.0 documentation and SO posts you are referring to.

Just to be crystal clear, you **don't** need a `DbSet<T>` returning **property** in your context. But you **do** need to [include the type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model) (keyless or not) in the model using the `modelBuilder.Entity<T>()` call, and also `ToView(null)` to prevent EF Core migrations associate database table and/or view with it, and *optionally* `HasNoKey()` in case you don;t want to use EF Core dependent attributes like `[Keyless]` in your data classes.

So the minimum requirement for your example is this line

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<BlogPostDto>().ToView(null);
```

Now, this is a long time requested feature (which exists in the "obsolete" EF6 which the "modern" EF Core is supposed to replace), tracked by [Support raw SQL queries without defining an entity type for the result #10753](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10753) issue in EF Core issue tracker. It was initially [planned to be included in the upcoming EF Core 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan) release (Nov 2022), but later [has been cut](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27185) for (eventually) EF Core 8.0 (Nov 2023). So until then you **have** to use the "register model" approach, or use 3rd party library(!) like Dapper for the same task, as suggested by one of the EF Core team members(?!).

Comment: Thanks for a great summary. It's beyond me how long it took them to create this feature. It's so easy to call a stored procedure in the old Entity Framework.