# Is there an EF Core equivalent of ExecuteFunction from EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In our `.NET Framework` solution, we're running stored procedures (whose return types aren't stored in the database) as such:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<stored_procedure_model_not_in_database>("sp_name", sp params)
```

I'm working on a microservice using `.NET 6` and trying to refactor the above to run the same stored procedure that has the same return type. So I want to run a stored procedure on a given `DbContext` instance where the return value's type isn't stored in the database. The closest I found was this:

```
_myDbContext.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy().Execute()
```

Where the Execute method is structured as such:

```
Execute<TState,TResult>(TState, Func<TState,TResult> operation, Func<TState,ExecutionResult<TResult>>? veritySucceeded)
```

But I'm not sure how the functions or TState would look, if this is even the proper way to go. I'm open to any ideas or suggestions and thank you in advance!

Edit: I think I may have found a possible solution in this SO post:
[getting return type from stored procedure without creating DbSet in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73616538/can-i-get-return-type-from-stored-procedure-without-creating-dbset-in-ef-core)

Will update as soon as I've tested to close this one out.

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools,  ir maps stored procedures for you

Comment: For executing stored procedures we've been using Dapper for years now. It's so much easier. Dapper is at least as popular as EF.

Comment: And you can use Dapper and EF together.