# How to Query (RAW SQL) Database using EntityFramework Core Version 7 without using a DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to pull data from several tables using EF Core V7.The issue is that i don't want to create models(`Datsets`) or do the `Onmodlecreation` binding for all the tables from which i'm pulling the data from. Basically i'm trying to execute a Raw SQL Query and get data into a object with a data model which does not exist in the database.

I have referred to this SO post

[Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)
It says `dbData.Database.SqlQuery` is now deprecated

and it speaks about several ways to solve it

1. To use a Keyless entity type- I don't understand how we are pulling data without a model binding to the context. Is it possible ?
2. To use a Helper class - It essentially executes Raw SQL. It raises the question of whether we need EF altogether to accomplish this .

Comment: Use Dapper then. Using EF without model has no sense.