# How to get the list of data returned from stored procedure while using ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using `ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync` in my .NET 6 Entity Framework Core project, and I am expecting to get a list of items as result, but it's just returning -1.

This is my code:

```
public async Task<int> Report(string sStartDate, string sEndDate, string spName)
{
    try
    {
        #region Fetch From DB
        var paramToDt = new SqlParameter("@TODATE", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        paramToDt.Value = sStartDate;

        var paramFrmDt = new SqlParameter("@FROMDATE", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        paramFrmDt.Value = sEndDate;

        var data = await Task.Run(() => _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($"EXEC {spName} @TODATE={paramToDt},@FROMDATE={paramFrmDt}"));      
        #endregion

        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }    
}
```

While debugging and seeing the value in the data object it showed as -1, but I expected a list because in the stored procedure, there is a select statement.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`ExecuteSqlInterpolated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlinterpolatedasync?view=efcore-6.0) method,

> Executes the given SQL against the database and returns the number of rows affected.

Instead, you should use either [`FromSqlInterpolated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlinterpolated?view=efcore-6.0) or [`FromSqlRaw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.fromsqlraw?view=efcore-6.0) method in order to fetch the queried records from the SQL.

Note that this requires creating a `DbSet` with a keyless entity type. Unless you are using EF Core 7.0 which supports [Querying scalar (non-entity) types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types) via `_context.Database.Query<T>()`.
Reference: [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452479/8017690)

```cs
public DbSet<EntityModel> EntityModels { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityModel>().HasNoKey();
}
```

And you need to modify the return type of the `Report` method as `List<EntityModel>` with `EntityModel` is your model class for the queried record.

```cs
public async Task<List<EntityModel>> Report(string sStartDate, string sEndDate, string spName)
{
    try
    {
        #region Fetch From DB
        var paramToDt = new SqlParameter("@TODATE", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        paramToDt.Value = sStartDate;

        var paramFrmDt = new SqlParameter("@FROMDATE", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        paramFrmDt.Value = sEndDate;

        var data = await _dbContext.EntityModels
            .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC {spName} @TODATE={paramToDt},@FROMDATE={paramFrmDt}")
            .ToListAsync();      

        #endregion
        return data;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }    
}
```

Note that `throw ex;` will not preserve the original stack trace information of the exception. You should be concerned regarding it, or else you should use `throw;` or remove the `try-catch` block as there is no further action to be handled when the exception is hit.

Reference: [Querying scalar (non-entity) types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types)

Comment: Hi Yong, I tried your code but after that, I am getting this below error:-
**Error CS1929 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'FromSqlInterpolated' and the best extension method overload 'RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlInterpolated<Report>(DbSet<Report>, FormattableString)' requires a receiver of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Proj.Repositories.Implementation.Report>**

Comment: Hi apologize for that, I amend the answer, please look. Thanks.