# Get nextvalue of sequence in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am trying to get the nextvalue of a sequence for my blazorserver.

The sequence was created long ago in the existing database.

And I want to retrive the value throught my newly developed blazorserver.

**Model Builder**

```
modelBuilder.HasSequence<long>("sequence_name");
```

**Code**

```
var seq = _db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("select nextval('sequence_name')");
```

**Result**

```
seq = -1
```

What is the correct way to get the next value of the sequence?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24926

Comment: If you execute that same SQL in SSMS, do you get the expected value? I'm not sure about the syntax you're using but I've used `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR sequence_name` and I've seen `SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL`. Do either of those work for you?

Comment: By the way, you can have the sequence value inserted automatically by using something like this in your entity configuration: `modelBuilder.Property(entity => entity.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR sequence_name");`. Not sure whether that's useful in your scenario or not.

Comment: [Querying scalar (non-entity) types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types)

Comment: @jmcilhinney: `nextval` is how Postgres does it. It would've been nice if OP had included the tag for the RDBMS.

Comment: @madreflection, good point. I guess I shouldn't have assumed either, but wouldn't have if the database had been specified.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. It is a Postgres database and the there is not an entity to include the specific sequence. I guess the original coder just treat this sequence as a parameter and it would be better if this sequence is included into a field of a table (like a Primary Key).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw SQL Query without DbSet - Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631903/raw-sql-query-without-dbset-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [Querying scalar (non-entity) types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types), LINQ and SQL can be used together for the entityless types.

```
var seq = _db.Database.SqlQueryRaw<long>("select nextval('sequence_name')");
```

Comment: In your question, you said you used `HasSequence<long>`, so I edited your answer to use `SqlQueryRaw<long>`. Make sure you do the same in your code.