String interpolation inside a formattable string in C#
I am in the process of replacing Dapper with EF Core in a project. Specifically using the new Database.SqlQuery and Database.ExecuteSql functionality with EF Core. I like how they use FormattableString to handle SQL parameters.
However I am confused on what to do when I would like to use both string interpolation and the curly braces for parameters with the FormattableStrings? Se example below of a Dapper version and a non-working EF Core version. I would not like the "subSql" to be passed as a parameter but just to create the string.
How would I approach this?
public IEnumerable<Something> GetSomethingWithDapper(string id, bool enabled, string type)
{
    var subSql = switch (type) {
        case "A":
            "TableA";
            break;
        case "B":
            "TableB";
            break;
    };
    
    var sql = $"SELECT * FROM {subSql} WHERE Id = @id";
    
    // My dapper request here
}

public IEnumerable<Something> GetSomethingWithEFCore(string id, string type)
{
    var subSql = switch (type) {
        case "A":
            "TableA";
            break;
        case "B":
            "TableB";
            break;
    };
    
    FormattableString sql = $"SELECT * FROM {subSql} WHERE Id = {id}";
    
    // My EF Core request here
}


If you use EF Core why are you using raw SQL at all? EF Core is an ORM, not a database driver. It tries to give the impression of working with in-memory entities instead of tables and rows. It's EF's job to generate the query from the entities and their relations, not yours. Instead of this code, all you really need is var customer=context.Customers.Find(id);. And if you want the customer's orders, var customer=context.Customers.Include(c=>c.Orders).Find(id);

We use both Dapper and EF Core. Dapper only when we need to get data that are not just a representation of the models. This parts I would like to replace now since EF Core do support this.

Why not add it to the model? And why move away from Dapper? Support and Is Better aren't the same. You're obviously mapping the full table, so why isn't Something part of the model?

Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452479/25070013

@PekoMiko No I see nothing about strint interpolation in that answer at all?

@PanagiotisKanavos I assume you understand that my example is not the actual case but only to represent the problem with string interpolation? I do not think you have to over analyze the model structure in this exampel.
We use 90% EF Core and 10% Dapper today. We simply would like to replace the last 10% that we have use Dapper due to this not being possible to do in EF Core before.
I am a big fan of Dapper but would like to reduce the amount of packages needed. I am very aware of the strengths of the package so you do not have to try to convince me :)

You're asking the wrong question to begin with. You're trying to use interpolation for two different things: creating a parameterized query and constructing the query string. That just won't work. You'll have to create the string "SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE Id = {id}" before you create a FormattableString that expects an id parameter.

@PanagiotisKanavos Great! This is exactly what I am asking for. How I should do this! How would I do this?

The equivalent to Dapper isn't using Formattable strings anyway, it's FromSqlRaw. You can write FromSqlRaw(sql,id) the same way you did with Dapper. And I still prefer Dapper for this, because even though Marc Gravell works for Microsoft now, Dapper is more mature while the EF Core team only has this feature out for a couple of years. Dapper has a version that supports Native Compilation already, EF Core doesn't.

So the real question is how to escape curly brackets in string interpolation?.... Use double curly brackets...

@Selvin no it's not. There are no escaped parameters in a formattable string. Something either is text or a parameter.  FromSql treats all parameters in the formattable string as query parameters. There's no way to say that half the parameters should be used for string interpolation, half for query parameters.

The equivalent to Dapper's QueryAsync<Something>(sql,id) is SqlQueryRaw, not SqlQuery or FromSql. SqlQuery and FromSql will treat all parameters in a FormattableString as query parameters. There's no way to tell that some of those parameters should be used for string interpolation and some for other things.
With SqlQueryRaw, the equivalent to Dapper's con.Query<int>(sql,new {id}) is context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<int>(sql,new{id}) eg:
var id= new SqlParameter("id", 45);
var ids = context.Database
    .SqlQueryRaw<int>("SELECT Id from TableX where id=@id",@id)
    .ToList();

Or
var sql=$"SELECT Id from {table} where id=@id";
var ids = context.Database
    .SqlQueryRaw<int>("SELECT Id from TableX where id=@id",id)
    .ToList();

This is also shown in the EF SQL query docs, in the Dynamic SQL and Parameters section:

If you've decided you do want to dynamically construct your SQL, you'll have to use FromSqlRaw, which allows interpolating variable data directly into the SQL string, instead of using a database parameter:

var columnName = "Url";
var columnValue = new SqlParameter("columnValue", "http://SomeURL");

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM [Blogs] WHERE {columnName} = @columnValue", columnValue)
    .ToList();

